# Regex to match all C style tokens but ignore double strings

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am parsing C-like syntax and would like to match all C Identifiers but ignore double-quoted strings and ignore certain keywords. For instance, in the following:

*hello "hello" floop "hello this is me" if else return noobie_234*

I want to match hello, floop, and noobie_234.

Here is what I've got so far:
`@"(\b(?!""|if|else|return)[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z_0-9]+(?!"")\b)"`

It works for all but the double-quoted strings with spaces in it, i.e., "hello this is me"
Any ideas what I need to do to also exclude double-quoted strings with spaces?

Comment: @RifloSnake, this pattern matches 123 and 1Something. These are not legal C Identifiers and need to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

***This regex will work:***

```
(?<!")\w+(?![\w\s]*\w"|")
```

Note that it doesn't exclude the `if`, `else`, `return` keywords, I think we shouldn't complicate regex any more and should do that filtering through simple if else blocks in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Building on RifloSnake's solution, I came up with this. It seems to work.
What it doesn't do is exclude the `if`, `else`, and `return` keywords. I can handle these cases post-processing.

`\b(?<!"")[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z_0-9]+(?![\w\s]*\w""|"")\b`